# How to post the content from ajax to controller in codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I could not post my data to controller. I am using codeigniter framework. I need to perform autocomplete action with database. I could not send the typed or selected data from view to controller through ajax. Here is my ajax function:

```
var i=$('table tr').length;

$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
    count=$('table tr').length;

    var data="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td><td><span id='snum"+i+"'>"+count+".</span></td>";
    data +="<td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='countryname_"+i+"' name='countryname[]'/></td> <td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='country_no_"+i+"' name='country_no[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='phone_code_"+i+"' name='phone_code[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='country_code_"+i+"' name='country_code[]'/></td></tr>";
    $('table').append(data);
    row = i ;
    $('#countryname_'+i).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/billing/get_country",
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'post',
            data: {
               name_startsWith: request.term,
               type: 'country_table',
               row_num : row
            },
             success: function( data ) {
                 response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    var code = item.split("|");
                    return {
                        label: code[0],
                        value: code[0],
                        data : item
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    autoFocus: true,            
    minLength: 0,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
        id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id_arr.split("_");                 
        $('#country_no_'+id[1]).val(names[1]);
        $('#phone_code_'+id[1]).val(names[2]);
        $('#country_code_'+id[1]).val(names[3]);
    }               
  });
```

Comment: Is `admin/billing/get_country` set up to receive and process the `$_POST` data?

Comment: You are doing right thing just make sure that <?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/billing/get_country is a valid url where admin is your controller name and billing is the function inside that controller

Comment: i have set my route like <?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/billing/get_country calls admin_billing/get_country

Comment: I need to post data to admin/billing/get_country @user2959229

Comment: Is web console showing code status 200 for that url? If not, check your base_url function. If yes, make sure your controller is calling to correct function for that url.

Comment: No other mistake in my code. I have correct url

Comment: Is your controller echoing output or returning it?

Answer (score 0):

Change This

```
url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/billing/get_country",
```

To this,

```
 url     :   '<?php echo site_url('admin/billing/get_country');?>',
```